# VS2008 report using values from a parametized Stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to generate a report showing payslips for a single employee using values from a SP with parameter values that have been passed from a datagrid row. However the report that is generated is blank. What am I missing. Below is what I have.

First I populate the datagrid view using values returned by a function called "sqlselect"

```
Dim dbcall As New dbcalls
    dtgPayslip_Old.DataSource = dbcall.sqlselect("empno AS Employee_Number,empname AS Employee_Name, date AS Date", "payrollarchiveview")
```

Secondly i select empno from datagrid view as the parameter value which I pass to the SP

```
Private Sub dtgPayslip_Old_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dtgPayslip_Old.CellDoubleClick
    Dim dbcall As New dbcalls
    Dim empno As String = dtgPayslip_Old.Item(0, dtgPayslip_Old.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString()

    dbcall.CallparametizedSP("payrollarchivedataview", "@e", empno)
```

The sub that makes a db call

```
Public Sub CallparametizedSP(ByVal procedureName As String, ByVal parameter As String, ByVal value As String)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, value)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = procedureName
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
```

After all this I would expect details of the employee into the report But all I get are the column headings. How can I resolve this. Thank you community

Comment: I am able to produce a crystal report fine with the same data source......NOW....Over to U team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the Form Load event of the report having the Report Viewer control, I added a parameter to the TableAdapter in this form

```
Me.TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.SP, paramenter)
```

The dbcall to the sub was unnecessary because the parameter value was obtained directly from the datagrid on click.